# How to style CSS for input box's width as a percentage when it has border and padding?

Tags: html, css, forms

If the container is 500px wide, and the label is 30% wide, and the input box is 70% wide, then supposedly everything should fit, but the catch is that the input box has a border left and right for 4px, and padding left and right for 2px, making it 6px wider than it is.

We can hack it by making the width not 70%, but 68% or something, but this is somewhat hacky.  Is there a way to handle it?  (We cannot do CSS reset, because the input box does need a border usually, assuming we don't hack it by using outline, which doesn't occupy any space).

The CSS:

```
#my-container { width: 500px }
#first-name-label { display: inline-block; width: 30% }
#first-name { display: inline-block; width: 70% }
```

The following are some examples:

1. http://jsfiddle.net/hNaM7/12/   outWidth: 356 (for the input box, as shown in debug console)
2. http://jsfiddle.net/hNaM7/13/   outerWidth 351
3. http://jsfiddle.net/hNaM7/14/   outerWidth 349
4. http://jsfiddle.net/hNaM7/15/   outerWidth 349
5. http://jsfiddle.net/hNaM7/20/ won’t wrap, but input box will go
   beyond the width of container

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: interesting, seems like you are saying use `box-sizing: border-box` to solve it... http://jsfiddle.net/hNaM7/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the width's are not accurate is because they are set to `box-sizing:content-box;`, which is the default setting for `box-sizing`. When the `width` and `height` are calculated in CSS, the `border` and `padding` are calculated on the outside of that `width` and `height`, adding additional space even if it's set to `width:100%;`. In order to counteract this, you simply need to set the element with the border to `box-sizing:border-box;`. That brings both the border and the padding inside of the width and height calculation.

**Try this:**

```
#my-container { width: 500px; }
#first-name-label { display: inline-block; width: 30%; }
#first-name {
   display:inline-block;
   width: 70%;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari, other WebKit */
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
   box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

**Or if you want to be more specific to just text inputs, try this:**

```
input[type=text] {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari, other WebKit */
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
   box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

**CSS Syntax:**

```
box-sizing: content-box|border-box|initial|inherit;
```

**Browser Support:**

```
Chrome (any): box-sizing
Opera 8.5+: box-sizing
Firefox (any): -moz-box-sizing
Safari 3: -webkit-box-sizing (unprefixed in 5.1+ versions)
IE8+: box-sizing
```

If you'd like to learn more about this, you can find a very informative article on box-sizing here:

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-sizing/

Comment: do you need `-webkit-box-sizing`?  What version of Chrome/Safari will require it?

Comment: I updated my answer with browser support info. Chrome does not require the prefix in any version, it has always supported box-sizing. Safari will require the prefixed version for anything lower than version 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/hNaM7/21/

```
#my-container { width: 500px }
#first-name-label { display: inline-block; width: 30% }
#first-name { display: inline-block; width: 70%; margin: 0 -3px;}
```

Comment: interesting solution... although I usually try not to use negative margin

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/fA75f/5/

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

```
*,:before,:after {
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#my-container {
  width:500px;
}

#first-name-label {
  display:inline-block;
  width:30%;
}

#first-name {
  display:inline-block;
  width:70%;
}
```

Comment: I applied `box-sizing:border-box` only to the input box and it worked even on IE 8. See http://jsfiddle.net/hNaM7/23/ or http://fiddle.jshell.net/hNaM7/23/show/ quite amazing

Comment: I noticed you applied `box-sizing:border-box;` to `*,:before,:after` --- this might be too much, as it essentially change the box model to IE quirks mode

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
border-style: hidden
```

?

It's supposed to help ease border conflicts in table elements, which is sort of the same problem you're having.

Comment: but as in the original question, I do want a border for the input box (or else how do people know it is there unless if you add a background to it? but the design team may not want a background)

Comment: so border the parent element instead?

Comment: (1) have you tried? (2) what does it mean when the container has border and the input box has no border?

Comment: I wouldn't say it means anything in terms of actual code manifestation, I should think that you'd see no difference if there were no border and no margin around the form element either, but just around the container. This might prevent it from looking wonky. It's only my two cents!